# Отменить рекурсию

Tags: javascript, функции, рекурсия, function-overloading

Всем привет)))

Есть функция - autoPlay()

```js
function autoPlay(startIndex, interval){
  var interval = interval || 6000
  var startIndex = startIndex || 0
  var headerLinks = $('header.home .links .link')
  setHeaderLinkClassActive(headerLinks[startIndex])
  changeBg(headerLinks[startIndex])
  setTimeout(function(){
   startIndex++
   startIndex < 3 ? autoPlay(startIndex,interval) : autoPlay( 0 ,interval)
   console.log( " clickActive = " + clickActive)
  },interval)
 }
```

Как перезаписать ее вызов. Получается я ее вызываю, а потом мне надо еще раз ее вызвать, но чтобы старый вызов уже убился

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы повторно вызываете `autoPlay` еще где-то:

```js
var timer;
function autoPlay(startIndex, interval){
  // ...
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    // ...
  }, interval);
}
```

Если не вызываете, то никакой отмены не нужно.